# Parse PHP file variables from Python script

Tags: php, python, regex

I need to get some data from PHP(Wordpress) config files from my Python script. How I can parse config data? For example, how I can get **$wp_version** value?
Config example:

```php
/**
 * The WordPress version string
 *
 * @global string $wp_version
 */
$wp_version = '3.5.1';

/**
 * Holds the WordPress DB revision, increments when changes are made to the WordPress DB schema.
 *
 * @global int $wp_db_version
 */
$wp_db_version = 22441;

/**
 * Holds the TinyMCE version
 *
 * @global string $tinymce_version
 */
$tinymce_version = '358-23224';

/**
 * Holds the required PHP version
 *
 * @global string $required_php_version
 */
$required_php_version = '5.2.4';

/**
 * Holds the required MySQL version
 *
 * @global string $required_mysql_version
 */
$required_mysql_version = '5.0';

$wp_local_package = 'en_EN';
```

Comment: If you have access to PHP, it maybe more robust to use PHP to tokenise the source file and output the structure in a more Python-friendly format - using [token_get_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) for example.

Comment: try https://github.com/ramen/phply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know that a simple variable in PHP is like `$foo = 'bar';`, let's create a regex that does not take in account something like `$_GET` or `$foo['bar']`:

1. Start with `$`, note that we need to escape it:
   `\$`
2. The first character after `$` can't be a number and has to be a letter or underscore:
   `\$[a-z]`
3. Then there may be a letter or digits or underscore after it:
   `\$[a-z]\w*`
4. Let's put the parenthesis:
   `\$([a-z]\w*)`
5. Now then there should be the "equal sign", but to make it more compatible, let's make the spaces optional:
   `\$([a-z]\w*)\s*=\s*`
6. After this there should be a value and it ends with a `;`:
   `\$([a-z]\w*)\s*=\s*(.*?);$`
7. We will use the `m` modifier which make `^$` match start and end of line respectively.
8. You can then use a trimming function to get ride of the single and double quotes.

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wD2iN6)</kbd>

> <sub>**Note 1:** This regex will fail at nested variables **$fail = 'en_EN'; $fail2 = 'en_EN';**</sub>
>   <sub>**Note 2:** Don't forget to use the **i** modifier to make it case insensitive.</sub>

Comment: Your regex is working pretty good! But I add quotes and remove new line symbol from end: **\$([a-z]\w*)\s*=\s*\'(.*?)\';**

Answer (score 2):

I've written a little python script to get pull database login information from wordpress's `wp-config.php` file for doing automatic site backups.

Here is the relevant part of my code (GitHub's syntax highlighting has trouble with Python's triple quoted strings):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

define_pattern = re.compile(r"""\bdefine\(\s*('|")(.*)\1\s*,\s*('|")(.*)\3\)\s*;""")
assign_pattern = re.compile(r"""(^|;)\s*\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)\s*=\s*('|")(.*)\3\s*;""")

php_vars = {}
for line in open("wp-config.php"):
  for match in define_pattern.finditer(line):
    php_vars[match.group(2)]=match.group(4)
  for match in assign_pattern.finditer(line):
    php_vars[match.group(2)]=match.group(4)
```

Comment: That's awesome!! Thanks for sharing. One thing it doesn't parse are defines with boolean or int values like `define('MULTISITE', true);`. I fixed the regex for this with `('|"?)` but then had to strip extra spaces on the resulting value...like when it is entered as `define( 'MULTISITE', true );`