# Python regular expression for PHP array parsing

Tags: php, python, regex, arrays, string

I have a function which parses PHP array declarations from files. The function then returns a dictionary with the keys being the keys of the PHP array and the values in python are the values from the PHP array.

### Example file:

```
$lang['identifier_a'] = 'Welcome message';
$lang['identifier_b'] = 'Welcome message.
You can do things a,b, and c here.

Please be patient.';
$lang['identifier_c'] = 'Welcome message2.
You can do things a,b, and c here.
Please be patient.';
$lang['identifier_d'] = 'Long General Terms and Conditions with more text';
$lang['identifier_e'] = 'General Terms and Conditions';
$lang['identifier_f'] = 'Text e';
```

### Python function

```
def fetch_lang_keys(filename):
    from re import search;
    import mmap;

    ''' fetches all the language keys for filename '''
    with open(filename) as fi:
        lines = fi.readlines();

    data = {};
    for line in lines:
        obj = search("\$lang\[[\'|\"](.{1,})[\'|\"]\] = [\'|\"](.{1,})[\'|\"];", line);
#        re.match(r'''\$lang\[[\'|\"](.{1,})[\'|\"]\] = [\'|\"](.{1,})[\'|\"];''', re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE);

        if obj:
            data[obj.group(1)] = obj.group(2);

    return data;
```

**This function should return a dictionary which should look like this:**

```
data['identifier_a'] = 'Welcome message'
data['identifier_b'] = 'Welcome message.
You can do things a,b, and c here.

Please be patient.';
// and so on
```

The regexp which is used in the function works for everything except for **identifier_b** and **identifier_c**, because the regular expression does not match blank lines and/or lines which do not end with ;. The wildcard operator with ; at the end did work either, because it matched too much.

Do you have any idea of how to solve this? I looked into lookahead assertions, but failed to use them properly. Thanks.

Comment: `[\'|\"]` => http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex seems to work. -

```
\$lang\[[\'|\"](.{1,})[\'|\"]\] = [\'|\"]((?:.|\n)+?)[\'|\"];
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bG7dZ8) here-

Comment: How would i allow this character '|' in the values too? (Without quotation marks)

Comment: Another special case occured which i am not to sure about: The value of the PHP array contained '...to Member\'s value...', which was not matched. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Well, why my answer is not a solution for your regexp problem, but nevertheless: why don't you wish to use a "real PHP parser" instead of home-brew regexp's? It could be much more reliable and might even be faster, and certainly a more maintainable solution.

Quick googling gave me: https://github.com/ramen/phply . But also I've found this: [Parse PHP file variables from Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16881577/parse-php-file-variables-from-python-script) . Hope this help.

Comment: phply unfortunately does not work as it does not parse the multi line php strings correctly.

Comment: well, its unit-tests have testcases for multiline strings, but probably they don't cover your case. I'll check.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the dot doesn't match newlines. You must use the singleline modifier (`re.DOTALL`) instead of the multiline modifier. Example:

```
obj = re.search(r'\$lang\[[\'"](.+?)[\'"]\] = [\'"](.+?)[\'"];', line, re.DOTALL);
```